# architecture of an LSTM network

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

how could I graph an LSTM network made in python with Keras. The network receives 6 different parameters as input and returns a value that is the forecast. The neural network was set up as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(512,input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()

Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 512)               1062912   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 513       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,063,425
Trainable params: 1,063,425
Non-trainable params: 0
```

would the image below be a good representation ?

[image: image-link]

If the image is not correct, could I use a representation with normal neurons instead of LSTM cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. Some modifications you could do to improve the graph are to represent it horizontally (forward pass from left to right), add some style to the individual layer titles and descriptions, replace the word *neurons* with the word *units* when referring to the LSTM units, and add some colors to accentuate the difference between features, units, and neurons. Here is an example:

[image]